# How to get XML doc from downloaded zip file in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml

I have used Typhoeus to stream a zip file to memory, then am iterating through each file to extract the XML doc. To read the XML file I used Nokogiri, but am getting an error, `Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - my_xml_doc.xml`.

I looked up the error and saw that ruby is most likely running the script in the wrong directory. I am a little confused, do I need to save the XML doc to memory first before I can read it as well?

Here is my code to clarify further:

**Controller**

```
def index
  url = "http://feed.omgili.com/5Rh5AMTrc4Pv/mainstream/posts/"
  html_response = Typhoeus.get(url)
  doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html_response.response_body)

  path_array = []
  doc.search("a").each do |value|
    path_array << value.content if value.content.include?(".zip")
  end

  path_array.each do |zip_link|
    download_file = File.open zip_link, "wb"
    request = Typhoeus::Request.new("#{url}#{zip_link}")
    binding.pry

    request.on_headers do |response|
      if response.code != 200
        raise "Request failed"
      end
    end

    request.on_body do |chunk|
      download_file.write(chunk)
    end

    request.run

    Zip::File.open(download_file) do |zipfile|
      zipfile.each do |file|
        binding.pry
        doc = Nokogiri::XML(File.read(file.name))
      end
    end
  end

end
```

**file**

```
=> #<Zip::Entry:0x007ff88998373
@comment="",
@comment_length=0,
@compressed_size=49626,
@compression_method=8,
@crc=20393847,
@dirty=false,
@external_file_attributes=0,
@extra={},
@extra_length=0,
@filepath=nil,
@follow_symlinks=false,
@fstype=0,
@ftype=:file,
@gp_flags=2056,
@header_signature=009890,
@internal_file_attributes=0,
@last_mod_date=18769,
@last_mod_time=32626,
@local_header_offset=0,
@local_header_size=nil,
@name="my_xml_doc.xml",
@name_length=36,
@restore_ownership=false,
@restore_permissions=false,
@restore_times=true,
@size=138793,
@time=2016-10-17 15:59:36 -0400,
@unix_gid=nil,
@unix_perms=nil,
@unix_uid=nil,
@version=20,
@version_needed_to_extract=20,
@zipfile="some_zip_file.zip">
```

Comment: Do you always know what the size range of these xml files are going to be? If not and if they have the possibility to be rather large you might want to save them to disk prior to manipulating them.

Comment: I will not always know the size, thank you for the suggestion! Ultimately I will be  putting the XML directly into a Redis list. (Haven't gotten that far yet in the code).

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I came up with:

**Gems:**

```
gem 'typhoeus'
gem 'rubyzip'
gem 'redis', '~>3.2'
```

**Controller:**

```
def xml_to_redis_list(url)
  html_response = Typhoeus.get(url)
  doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html_response.response_body)
  @redis = Redis.new

  path_array = []
  doc.search("a").each do |value|
    path_array << value.content if value.content.include?(".zip")
  end

  path_array.each do |zip_link|
    download_file = File.open zip_link, "wb"
    request = Typhoeus::Request.new("#{url}#{zip_link}")

    request.on_headers do |response|
      if response.code != 200
        raise "Request failed"
      end
    end

    request.on_body do |chunk|
      download_file.write(chunk)
    end

    request.run

    while download_file.size == 0
      sleep 1
    end

    zip_download = Zip::File.open(download_file.path)
    Zip::File.open("#{Rails.root}/#{zip_download.name}") do |zip_file|
      zip_file.each do |file|
        xml_string = zip_file.read(file.name)
        check_if_xml_duplicate(xml_string)
        @redis.rpush("NEWS_XML", xml_string)
      end
    end
    File.delete("#{Rails.root}/#{zip_link}")
  end

end

def check_if_xml_duplicate(xml_string)
  @redis.lrem("NEWS_XML", -1, xml_string)
end
```